# Possibility of inserting manual columns between a Google Connected Sheet columns Powered by Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert a manual column in between a Big Query generated extract columns via Connected Sheet. Basically, I already have a Google Connected Sheet which is pulling from Big Query via SQL. Whenever I try to insert a manual column in between columns generated by the query though, it automatically moves the manual column to the very end on the right or to the very end on the left. I don't want this. I want to be able to insert a manual column in between a Big Query generated column in a Google Sheet.

Is it not possible to do this? Or is there another way to be able to pull something like this off? I can't find any videos or specific documentation on if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

See below answer to questions:

*Is it not possible to do this?*

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets#access_control):

> Direct access to BigQuery datasets and tables is still controlled within BigQuery. A user with Sheets-only access can perform analysis in the sheet and use other Sheets features, but the user will not be able to perform the following actions:
>
> 1. Manually refresh the BigQuery data in the sheet.
> 2. Schedule a refresh of the data in the sheet.

Hence, you cannot manually create a column when you use Connected Sheets when accessing Bigquery Data. The main function of Connected sheets in this use case is to analyze and visualize data from Bigquery, and not to manipulate data.

*Is there another way to be able to pull something like this off?*

Option 1: extract from Sheets the data from Bigquery
[image]

Then you can see that the Insert function is enabled. You may insert another column in this extracted sheet:
[image]

Option 2: Download the sheet as an excel file and insert column in between once downloaded:

[image]

Comment: I tried that in my original scenario. It will only move your column all the way to the right or all the way to the left. It won't allow you to insert a column in between the Extract.

Comment: If that's the case I suggest you Download the sheet itself as an excel file and add the column in between. I will add this option in the answer section as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the only option. It's a bit hacky but I guess that's all I can do for now. Thanks for the suggestion!